# C# Syntax error - CS1003 (Generating a CLI)

Tags: c#

```
static void Generations(int value = 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tGenerations: {0}", value.ToString());
}
static void Dimensions(int value = 16 16)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tRows: {0}\n\tColumns: {1}", value.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
                   Generations();
Dimensions();
```

Required Output:

```
Generations: 50
Rows: 16
Columns: 16
```

The error occurs at (int value = 16 16). Am I not allowed to pass 2 arguments {0} and {1} in the same one?

Comment: I recommend taking a [C# tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/) to learn basic syntax.

Comment: You can as two arguments `Dimensions(int first = 16, int second = 16)`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot store more than a multiple value in a single object. What you're looking for is an **Array**, which is a List in layman's terms.

You can define an array by suffixing your type with `[]`:

```
public static int FirstElementOFArray(int[] value) {
    return value[0]; //Returns the first element
}
```

You cannot have a default value for an array, as default values can only be compile-time constants, such as a simple string (`"hello world"`) and numbers (`11`, `11.5`).